# How do you use mod_rewrite to move a site down a sub directory?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a site with URLs like this:

```
http://domain.co.uk/subdir/page.php
```

I have redesigned the site so URLs are now like this:

```
http://domain.co.uk/page.php
```

How can I 301 redirect all the pages to their new locations using Apache's mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Update: Tested it, it works.

Comment: Is the full URL really needed? Seems like "RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]" should do the trick too.

Comment: @PEZ - it's not a bad idea to canonicalise the domain, and that's a side effect of doing the config this way

Comment: where should i write the script?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the trick, I believe:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```